# Giving a list as an argument to a Scrapy scraper

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to be able to give a list of urls as an argument to my scrapy scraper so that I can iterate on it at regular intervals to avoid 403 errors. For the moment I don't think Scrapy allows me to do this.

```
scrapy crawl nosetime -o results.jl ['/pinpai/10036120-yuguoboshi-hugo-boss.html', '/pinpai/10094164-kedi-coty.html', '/pinpai/10021965-gaotiye-jean-paul-gaultier.html', '/pinpai/10088596-laerfu-laolun-ralph-lauren.html']
```

Or else a file of urls.

For the moment these urls are hard written in my spider:

```
import scrapy
from ..pipelines import NosetimeScraperPipeline
import time

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; TencentTraveler 4.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618)'}
base_url = 'https://www.nosetime.com'

class NosetimeScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nosetime"

    urls = ['/pinpai/10036120-yuguoboshi-hugo-boss.html', # I want to get rid of this
            '/pinpai/10094164-kedi-coty.html',            # unless I can use something like time.sleep(12*60*60)
            '/pinpai/10021965-gaotiye-jean-paul-gaultier.html', # for each before being taken as argument
            '/pinpai/10088596-laerfu-laolun-ralph-lauren.html']

    start_urls = ['https://www.nosetime.com' + url for url in urls]
    base_url = 'https://www.nosetime.com'

    def parse(self, response):
        # proceed to other pages of the listings
        urls = response.css('a.imgborder::attr(href)').getall()
        for url in urls:
            print("url: ", url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=base_url + url, callback=self.parse)

        # now that we have the urls we need to know if the dire are the things we can scrape
        pipeline = NosetimeScraperPipeline()
        perfume = pipeline.process_response(response)
        try:
            if perfume['enname']:
                print("Finally are going to store: ", perfume['enname'])
                pipeline.save_in_mongo(perfume)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty simple example in [Scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments) that you can adjust to get a file name with a list of URLs:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -a urls_file=URLs.txt

   def __init__(self, urls_file=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.urls_file = urls_file
        # ...
   def start_requests(self):
       with open(self.urls_file, 'r') as f:
       # read and yield your URLs here
```